# Broadcom BCM4321 wireless doesn't work on battery

Tags: 11.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

Upgraded Ubuntu to 11.04, now wireless card does not work when I unplug the laptop

lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4

```
10:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1693] (rev 02)
30:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
```

Comment: are you connecting to your router using wireless "n" mode?  - check the settings in your router.  Does it work better when your router is set to either wireless "b" mode or wireless "g" mode?

Comment: Also add to you question the any output from "dmesg" when you disconnect the power.

Answer (score 1):

You could try finding out what driver your wireless card uses by running

```
lsmod | egrep "b43|wl|brcm80211"
```

and then running

```
sudo rmmod yourdriver
sudo modprobe yourdriver
```

Since your wireless card is the BCM4321, you're likely running the `wl` driver (a.k.a. Broadcom STA), so you would run

```
sudo rmmod wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: Thanks, executed the above commands, and now wireless works on battery with my laptop

Comment: You're welcome :D I'm glad I could help. If you want, you can create a shortcut on the desktop to do that for you: Ubuntu/GNOME/Unity: shortcut to `gksudo -- sh -c 'rmmod wl; sleep 2; modprobe wl'` OR Kubuntu/KDE: shortcut to `kdesudo -- sh -c 'rmmod wl; sleep 2; modprobe wl'`

Answer (score 0):

`pm-powersave` turns wireless OFF when switching to battery. See my answer [Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery)